# How can I access image by calling URL from a webapp

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have one webapp (`abc.war`) deployed on tomcat and there is an image folder , under this several images lying and I can access these images by URL: `xx.xx/abc/image/hello.jpg`

This project is running live but I am not able to get how these images are retrieved.

Now I have another REST based project deployed in tomcat and i want similar behaviour e.g 
`xx.xx/hellorest/images/anil.jpg`, but right now I am not able to access using above URL.

Need help how this can possible. I don't want to use any Servlet to read and write the Image.

Comment: "there is an image folder": where? What is `xx.xx`? How about... putting the images in the war file, inside a folder named `images` (assuming xx.xx is a host name and hellorest is the contest path of your webapp)?

Comment: yes image is folder inside abc.war and images is folder inside hellorest.war. xx.xx is hostname and abc and hellorest are different context path for these 2 applications. image/images folder are in parallel of WEB-INF folder.

Comment: So, this should work, unless you have a servlet mapped to `/images/*` or `/` and would thus be called instead of the default servlet serving static files. What happens when you go to `/hellorest/images/anil.jpg`?

Comment: when i called /hellorest/images/anil.jpg then i get below error --          HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Comment: Then either you have no file having this name in the war, or you have a servlet mapped to the same URL, and returning a 404. paste the result of `jar tvf mywar.war`. And tell us more about what servlets they are in this app and how they're mapped.

Comment: Issue Resolved, when i add <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
                        <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
                            </servlet-mapping>                                                                     Problem was, in web.xml all request(/*) gone through Jersey servlet .

Answer (score 0):

First, /WEB-INF is not accessible from the outside.

Second, if you use /images/temp.jpg, the browser will load images from the root of the web server, and not from the root of your web-app (which is deployed under a context path).

Use the JSTL  tag to generate absolute paths from the root of the web-app:
" alt=.../>